# What is the Endpoint/Port used for Google Cloud Speech API

Tags: google-cloud-speech

For using Google Cloud Speech API via the streaming API([Performing Streaming Speech Recognition on an Audio Stream](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize#performing_streaming_speech_recognition_on_an_audio_stream)),

what are the endpoints/ports we need to enable/whitelist?

The reason being asked is, we are running this on a restricted device, and need to open only the required outbound endpoints/ports.

Answer (score 5):

You should whitelist `*.googleapis.com` and `accounts.google.com`. These all are using https protocol.

The actual endpoint for speech is https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech, but you will also need to access authentication endpoints `accounts.google.com`, `www.googleapis.com`
and `oauth2.googleapis.com`.

Comment: Thanks. Hope this is same for gRPC stream API as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have got following URLs white-listed for the same

```
https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/* 
https://speech.googleapis.com/* 
https://accounts.google.com/*
https://www.googleapis.com/*
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/* 
https://cloud.google.com/*
```