# Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed with Google Speech API

Tags: google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

We have a NodeJS based Google Cloud Speech API component, which works fine in many environments, but in a particular environment, we are getting below error.

Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed

Any pointers where the issue is. We have a doubt this is related to connectivity, but how to confirm this?

Comment: We did some investigation assuming this is related to network accessibility. We blocked all outbound calls from the machine running this service, and we got this error. Then we enabled googleapis.com, speech.googleapis.com, oauth2.googleapis.com after which it started to work. So it's showing what we assumed. Can someone confirm this?

Comment: It turned up to be related with all the requests needing to be going through a proxy server. We tried https://medium.com/google-cloud/accessing-google-cloud-apis-though-a-proxy-fe46658b5f2a but it didn't work. Anyone have an idea about getting Cloud Speesh Streaming API to work with a proxy server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the tests you did about enabling *.googleapis.com, speech.googleapis.com, oauth2.googleapis.com confirm that traffic is blocked in your end. Such google endpoints should remain accessible to request the Speech service.

I hope that the following recommendations help you:

1. Traffic blocked by Proxy. The link you referenced should work, just check the section [NodeJS google-cloud-node](https://medium.com/google-cloud/accessing-google-cloud-apis-though-a-proxy-fe46658b5f2a). If you are using a programming language will need to set them up properly, this is [a Java example](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/proxy_setup).
2. Traffic blocked by Firewall. It is a bit more challenging due to involve Google Cloud IPs and they usually change. In such case you can find out those IPs with the command `dig _netblocks.google.com txt` and configure them in your firewall to allow the traffic.

This question is also related to yours: [What is the Endpoint/Port used for Google Cloud Speech API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51122469/what-is-the-endpoint-port-used-for-google-cloud-speech-api).

Comment: This was actually due to the proxy server we used not supporting http2, which was required for the gRPC calls used in this API. We ended up avoiding the gRPC calls via firewall and getting gRPC calls routed directly through the firewall.