# Flutter windows desktop app - google speech to text -gRPC Error (code: 14, codeName: UNAVAILABLE

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, google-speech-api, google-speech-to-text-api, flutter-windows

while calling google speech-to-text api from flutter desktop app for windows I end up getting this error. any idea anyone?

`gRPC Error (code: 14, codeName: UNAVAILABLE, message: Error making call: Null check operator used on a null value, details: null, rawResponse: null, trailers: {})`

Comment: Does this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250372/error-14-unavailable-connect-failed-with-google-speech-api) help you?